# ActiveRecord has a MyModel.delete(...) method, while Mongoid does not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mongoid

We are currently migrating from MySQL to MongoDB, and I stumbled over the following:

```
MyModel.destroy(params[model_ids]) # Remove many objects at once by passing an array of IDs
```

This worked for ActiveRecord, but for MongoDB it doesn't: I have to iterate over the IDs, find it, and then call the `delete` method on the instantiated object:

```
MyModel.find(params[model_ids]).each do |item|
  item.destroy
end
```

Is this the correct way to go? And is there a special reason why Mongoid doesn't offer the mentioned functionality?

Thank you!

Comment: sidenote: you' d rather always use `destroy` instead of `delete`

Comment: You're right, I just corrected it. More infos see [here](http://www.pmamediagroup.com/2009/04/activerecord-destroy-vs-delete/).

Comment: This exists in Mongoid v3: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#query_plus

Comment: so you should have the method available :)

Comment: Well, I don't! :P `erson.respond_to? :destroy
=> false`, `Person.first.respond_to? :destroy
=> true`...

Comment: `Person` isn't a `Criteria`, `Person.where...` (or any scope) is one

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! Still very new to Mongoid... Newbie me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
MyModel.where(:_id.in => params[model_ids]).destroy
```

In Mongoid you can run the destroy method on a criteria.

Comment: Looks like a copy/paste of my comments